# Typescript, JSX: render component, passed as argument

Tags: typescript, reactjs

I want to write a function, which renders react component, passed as argument to that function. I want to handle both `Component` and `StatelessComponent` types. This is how I do that:

```
function renderComponent(component: React.ComponentClass<any> | React.StatelessComponent<any>) {
    return <component />;
}
```

I got compilation error:

```
error TS2604: JSX element type 'component' does not have any construct or call signatures.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In your example your `renderComponent` function is getting an instance of a `Component` and not a class/ctor.
It should be:

```
function renderComponent(componentClass: { new (): React.ComponentClass<any> | React.StatelessComponent<any> }) {
    return <componentClass />;
}
```